# How To integerate a Razorpay Pyament Gateway with Webhooks In Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I implement a Razorpay payment gateway in my laravel website and it's working fine but needs to integrate it with webhooks and I don't understand how to use it my code so we get user payment status and save it in my database table.

**Payment Controller Code**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers\razorpay;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Payment;
use App\User;
use Auth;
use Redirect,Response;
use Carbon\Carbon; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use DB;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
public function show_products(){ 
    return view('razorpay.payment');
}

public function view(Request $request){

    $payments = DB::table("payments")
                ->orderBy('payments.created_at', 'DESC')
                ->get();

    return view('admin.all-transaction', compact('payments'));
}

public function add(){

    $users = DB::table("users")->get();
    return view('admin.add-transaction', compact('users'));
}

public function getUser($id)
{
    $users = DB::table("users")
                ->where("id",$id)
                ->get();
    return json_encode($users);
}

public function pay_success(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
        'name' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email', 
        'package' => 'required',
        'months' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'subtotal' => 'required',
        'discount' => 'required',
        'grandtotal' => 'required',

    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) { 
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['payment_id'] = str_random(40);
    $input['order_id'] = Str::random(40);
    date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
    $input['months'] = $request->months;       
    $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($input['months']);
    $input['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;

    $payment = Payment::create($input);

    $arr = array('msg' => 'Payment successful.', 'status' => true);

    return Response()->json($arr);    
}

public function thank_you()
{
    return view('razorpay.thankyou');
}

public function update_package()
{

    $userinformations = User::where('id', Auth::id())->get();

    //dd($userinformations);

    return view('frontend.views.upgrade-package', compact('userinformations'));
}

 public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        /*$input = $request->all();
        date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
        $input['months'] = $request->months;       
        $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($input['months']);
        $input['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;
        DB::table('users')->where('id',$request->id)->update($input);
        return response()->json($input);*/

        date_default_timezone_set('asia/calcutta');
        $months = $request->months; 
        $expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addMonths($months);  
        $request['expiry_date'] = $expiry_date;

        $data = ['id'=>$request->id, 'name'=>$request->name, 'phone'=>$request->phone, 'country'=>$request->country, 'state'=>$request->state,
                 'purpose'=>$request->purpose, 'package'=>$request->package, 'months'=>$months, 'quantity'=>$request->quantity, 'amount'=>$request->amount,  'expiry_date'=>$expiry_date,];
        DB::table('users')->where('id',$request->id)->update($data);


        return response()->json($data);
     }
     }
```

**Razorpya Integration Script**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var SITEURL = 'pay-success';
  //alert('SITEURL');
  $.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
 }
 }); 
 $('body').on('click', '.buy_now', function(e){
 var totalAmount = $('#grandtotal').val();
 // var totalAmount = $(this).attr("data-amount");
 //alert(totalAmount);
 var product_id =  $(this).attr("data-id");
 var options = {
 "key": "****************",
 "amount": (totalAmount*100), // 2000 paise = INR 20
 "name": "AddSpy",
 "description": "Payment",
 "image": "http://localhost:8000/frontend/images/addspy1.png",
 "handler": function (response){
        $.ajax({
        url: SITEURL,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "_token": $('#token').val(),
            razorpay_payment_id: response.razorpay_payment_id , 
            totalAmount : totalAmount ,product_id : product_id,
            user_id : $('#user_id').val(),
            name : $('#name').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            package : $('#package').val(),
            months : $('#months').val(),
            price  : $("#price").val(),
            subtotal : $("#subtotal").val(),
            discount : $("#discount").val(),
            grandtotal : $("#grandtotal").val(),
            expiry_date : $('#expiry_date').val(),

        }, 
        success: function (msg) {
                window.location.href = 'thank-you';
        }
       });
       },
       "prefill": {
       "contact": '1234567890',
       "email":   'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
       },
       "theme": {
       "color": "#528FF0"
       }
       };
       var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
       rzp1.open();
       e.preventDefault();
       });
    </script>
```

How to integrate webhooks code please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented razorpay couple of months back. At this moment I don't have access to my codebase but I can guide you in the right direction.

[image]

**Quick Overview**:

- Customer places an order on your website or app.
- Your server sends a **create order** request to Razorpay's server.
- In the response, Razorpay returns an `order_id`. You need to store this order_id in your database corresponding to the order on your end.
- Submit the `order_id` to the Checkout form on the website or app.
- In the Checkout, the customer enters the payment details.
- After the successful payment on the Checkout, send the following attributes to your server:

  - `razorpay_payment_id`
  - `razorpay_order_id`
  - `razorpay_signature`
- The details submitted in the Checkout are verified in your server.
- After successful verification at your end, you can now capture the payment.

**Step by step guide:** [docs](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/orders/integration/)

Comment: sir thanks for your answer but how I save my payment status in the database, please explain